# linux poll behaviour with infinite timeout

Tags: c, linux, polling

`poll` function in Linux waits for file descriptor (fd) to become ready. The functions wait for fd to become ready for the minimum time specified in its `timeout` argument.  Check the manual page [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) .

I understand that `poll` actively samples the file descriptor until it becomes ready. What is the sampling interval used by the `poll` function?

If the `timeout` is negative, then the `poll` function blocks for an infinite time. I would like to understand what would be the function behavior in this case.  Does the infinite time mean that thread calling `poll` can take CPU for infinite time?

Answer (score 3):

When calling poll() that block forever will not consume the cpu resource. It will be woken up by kernel when the fd become ready to read/write/exception handle.
It doesn't use the actual polling like its name, but interrupts.

Comment: Please add some reference to your answer

Comment: Well, since the alternative, continual CPU-intensive polling, is irrational, avoidable and pointless, why would a reference be needed?  You want evidence? Easy: set up a poll() of a load of fd for yourself, using an infinite timeout.  Check ps, task manager, whatever, for your CPU usage,stats....